# Как лучше организовать sql запрос

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я бы хотел узнать, как лучше сделать. Для каждого пользователя делать запрос в базу данных (mysqli) или сделать 1 большой запрос, поместить в массив и для каждого пользователя делать перебор из этого массива?

Comment: Надо написать вопрос подробнее что за пользователи, что за запрос, зачем делать перебор

Comment: если вы будете в итоге выводить инфу о всех пользователях, то конечно лучше большой запрос

Comment: Почему не передать этого пользователя в функцию или процедуру и в ней уже имея пользователя формировать там какой-то сложный запрос